# How MySQL does the math calculation of floating point addition?

Tags: mysql, sql, ieee-754

I tested with `SELECT 0.1 + 0.2;`, queried with MySQL (MariaDB), and it returned the right answer

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT 0.1 + 0.2;
+-----------+
| 0.1 + 0.2 |
+-----------+
|       0.3 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```

Floating point calculation is inaccurate in most programming languages because of [IEEE 754](http://grouper.ieee.org/groups/754/) as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/588014/5616565).

How MySQL does the floating point calculation that makes it return the right answer?

Comment: *In most programming languages it calculates it kinda wrong*: can you provide an actual example of a software that is not able to compute `0.1 + 0.2` accurately?

Comment: @GMB in Python it returns `0.30000000000000004`, also there are a lot of examples of other languages here => http://0.30000000000000004.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know SQL 92 is old standard but iám pretty sure this is not changed in the newer SQL standard versions.

SQL 92 defines

> 73)Subclause 6.12, `"<numeric value expression>"`: When the data type
>               of both operands of the **addition**. subtraction, multiplication,
>               or division operator is **exact numeric**, the precision of the
>               result is **implementation-defined.**"*
>
> 75)Subclause 6.12, `"<numeric value expression>"`: When the data
>               type of **either** operand of an arithmetic operator is **approximate
>               numeric**, the precision of the result is **implementation-defined.**"*

The question is: `0.1` and `0.2` in the query `SELECT 0.1 + 0.2` a approximate or is it exact? 
The answer is: you don't know also the database can't know. 
So the database will run the implemention defined for MySQL and MariaDB engines this seams to be handled as `DECIMAL(1,1)` datatypes

Why does Nick's answer return the correct values or expected ones with a table definition

SQL 92 also defines

> Implicit type conversion can occur in expressions, fetch opera-
>   tions, single row select operations, inserts, deletes, and updates.
>   Explicit type conversions can be specified by the use of the CAST
>   operator.

Which Nick has done by defining the datatype in the table.

**Edited this answer because i found something in the MySQL's manual today.**

The query

```
SELECT (0.1 + 0.2) = 0.3
```

Results into `1` in MySQL which means MySQL uses exact numeric calculation and uses [Precision Math](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/precision-math-examples.html) where possible.
So the MySQL does know that `0.1`, `0.2` and `0.3` are exact datatypes here and needs to calculate exact, like i was expecting before this edit.

Meaning the query

```
SELECT (0.1 + 0.2) = 0.3
```

will run under the hood more or less like

```
SELECT CAST((0.1 + 0.2) AS DECIMAL(1, 1)) = CAST((0.3) AS DECIMAL(1, 1));
```

Comment: @DarkSuniuM found something new today in the MySQL's manual i've edited the question

Answer (score 4):

That is just MySQL being intelligent in data type/formatting choice because you haven't specified that those values are floating point. Try this:

```
create table test (f float);
insert into test values (0.1), (0.2);
select sum(f) from test
```

Output:

```
sum(f)
0.30000000447034836
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=658b9b2d13b7f442736626c17e703d6e)

If you use double precision you get the classic `0.30000000000000004` result. [Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=212ed9ab6c8c7d5f04b6505e6b105751)

Comment: Seems like it's right, Can u explain how it's being intelligent? that's the important part for me, Thanks

Comment: @DarkSuniuM unfortunately I'm not that familiar with the internals of MySQL. I would suspect that it is just choosing to use `DECIMAL` for accuracy.

Comment: *"I'm not that familiar with the internals of MySQL. I would suspect that it is just choosing to use DECIMAL for accuracy. "* indeed @Nick it's been confirmed (just found it in the manual) MySQL uses exact numeric calculation  where [possible](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/precision-math-examples.html)

Comment: @RaymondNijland thanks for the update. It is nice to have it confirmed - I guess I should have hunted a bit harder. If I could upvote your answer again I would! :-)