# mysql decimal type column added with a string, loss of precision

Tags: sql, mysql, decimal, precision, loss

- tableName: tb_assets
- columnName: free
- columnType: decimal(32,16)
- sql-1: update  tb_assets set free = 16224.0221121221736466  where id=6;
- sql-2: update  tb_assets set free = free + '100000000' where id=6;
- after sql-1:
  fee: 16224.0221121221736466
- after sql-1&sql-2:
  fee: 100016224.0221121200000000
- compare:
  fee:     16224.0221121221736466
  fee: 100016224.0221121200000000
  100016224(after sql-2 executed,Integer part.loss precision with integer's digits - 1)

please help me understand why the decimal part will lose precision.

Explanation about why a decimal type column added with a string in Mysql, it will lose precision.

I wanna know what is the detail when execute the sql "update  tb_assets set free = free + '100000000' where id=6;"

Comment: Exactly what problem are you tackling that requires such an enormous range of precision?

Comment: Problem is reproduced here: https://dbfiddle.uk/Y0rm7T-4  My guess is that there is a maximum precision when handling numbers as strings - but I don't know if this is true or documented. Note: if you explicitly cast that string to decimal(32,16) the loss of precision does not occur.

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55329711/2067753 and https://dbfiddle.uk/5z6nbo0k when you add the string you restrict the result to double precision. So either don't add strings or cast the string to decimal(32,16) or signed if an integer